# How to solve dataframe and DictReader errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, beautifulsoup, python-requests

As my code works fine but on saving to CSV it gives me an error of Data frame Also gave me on Start of Code error **<csv.DictReader object at 0x000001B5CCE8D240>
[]** even the name of the file is different that's **multiple.py** in which I **uninstall/install** **Pandas** **library** also but nothing is solved yet.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import time
import pandas as pd 

def Gucci(url):
    headers={
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.5112.79 Safari/537.36'}
    r=requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    content = soup.find_all('a',class_='product-tiles-grid-item-link js-ga-track')
    time.sleep(6)
    for items in content:
        Title=items.find('div',class_='product-tiles-grid-item-info').h2.text
        price=items.find('p',class_='price').span.text.replace("CHF", "")
        Store='GUCCI'
        Product_Type='Coat'
        Category= 'Mens'
        Country='Switzerland'
    
        #print(Title,price,Store,Product_Type,Category)
        skechers={
            'Product_Name':Title,
            'Product_Price': price,
            'Store':Store,
            'Product_Type':Product_Type,
            'Category': Category, 
            'Country':Country           
        }
        skechersshoes.append(skechers)
    df = pd.DataFrame(skechersshoes)
    #print(df.head())
    print('ALL DONE ')
    df.to_csv('Gucci.csv')
    print('Saved to csv file')
    return
Gucci('https://www.gucci.com/ch/en_gb/ca/men/ready-to-wear-for-men/coats-for-men-c-men-readytowear-coats')
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have `skechersshoes` defined in your code. Just above `for items in content`, add this :

```
skechersshoes = []
```

The code works and I was able to get a list of 11 shoes [image]

Packages I used:

```
beautifulsoup4     4.11.1
bs4                0.0.1
numpy              1.23.3
pandas             1.4.4
```